# Make gif from multiple PNG files

Tags: java, png, gif

I'm trying to combine about 45 png files to make a gif, or to make a video, or some type of movie or animated image.

Please provide ideas for how I can do this? Is there free software I can download? Is there Java code I can write to do this? etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/).  There's plenty of documentation on [creating GIF animations](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/).

It may be as simple as:

```
convert -delay 20 -loop 0 *.png myanimation.gif
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a free program called [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/).
There are plenty of [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-9_HwRcd1A) on youtube saying how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Both ImageMagick and GIMP will do it. With ImageMagick and PhotoStage I got an animation working and exported to an .mp4 file.